# security command gives out passwords without prompting for the keychain password

Tags: macos, security, keychain

When I try to access a keychain password using the keychain access GUI, I always get a dialog box for inputting the current keychain (login) password.

[image]

However, when I try the same thing from the command line using commands like the following

```
security find-generic-password -gs site_name
```

there is no such dialog for password input and the password is just given without any form of validation.

Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 4):

I bumped into this same issue, and it seems its all about removing the default access when creating the new password, this is described on help of the command:

```
security add-generic-password -h
```

At the bottom you will see:

> By default, the application which creates an item is trusted to access its data without warning.
>   You can remove this default access by explicitly specifying an empty app pathname: -T ""
>   If no keychain is specified, the password is added to the default keychain.

So essentially you create the password with the `-T ""` setting:

```
security add-generic-password -a YOURUSER -s SERVICENAME -w YOURPASSWORD -T ""
```

Answer (score 1):

First try to unlock the keychain with `security unlock-keychain -p :the_keychain_password: :path_to_keychain:`